# Join 2 tables even with null values and sum each row

Tags: sql-server-2012

See pics below of what i want to do with my sql statement. I have used a left join and ISNULL to get all the results fine except for I don't get the total, which I want to sum the numbers for each customer. All table b values are integers.

```
Select a.CustomerId, a.FName, a.LName, b.mtg1, b.mtg2, b.mtg3, b.mtg4 From Customer a Left Join Hours b On a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID group by a.Lname
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` will make it a bit difficult to captured all the necessary data. Also, the sum of different columns will require the use of `COALESCE(column, 0) so as to use zero as the value if the column is null because if not done, your total will come back as`NULL`.

One possible solution will is:

```
SELECT a.CustId, a.FName, a.LName, SUM(b.mtg1), SUM(b.mtg2), SUM(b.mtg3), SUM(b.mtg4), (COALESCE(SUM(b.mtg1), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.mtg2), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.mtg3), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.mtg4), 0)) AS total
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON(b.CustID = a.CustId)
GROUP BY a.CustID, a.FName, a.LName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 with cte as
 (
 select flname+', '+fname as Name,
        mtg1,mtg2,mtg3,mtg4,
        isnull(((case when mtg1 is null then 0 else mtg1 end)+
                (case when mtg2 is null then 0 else mtg2 end)+
                (case when mtg3 is null then 0 else mtg3 end)+
                (case when mtg4 is null then 0 else mtg4 end)),0) as total

   from a left join b
   on   a.custid = b.custid

   )
   select name,
          isnull(mtg1,0) as mtg1,
          isnull(mtg2,0) as mtg2,
          isnull(mtg3,0) as mtg3,
          isnull(mtg4,0) as mtg4,
          total
   from cte
   order by 1
```